# SSLSocket receive and send requests without blocking thread

Tags: java, server, buffer, inputstream, sslsocketfactory

I'm trying to read from a SSLSocket server, I need the client to be open 24/7, Note I am only making the client, The server is already set up, I'm trying to read data and send data from the server, How ever when I do try to read the data it blocks my current thread and I can't seem to do anything else after that since the loop never ends, and if I make a loop that ends the program returns. I want it to be open always and keep getting incoming request and then send request back according to what I receive, this is what I currently have.

```
private SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
private SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(host, port);
private BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sslsocket.getOutputStream()));
private InputStream is = sslsocket.getInputStream();
```

these are the global vars I have defined, and this is how I write data to the server

```
private void write_to_server(String date) throws IOException {
    writer.write(date);
    writer.flush();
}
```

and finally this is how I receive response and this is where I am having the problem.

```
public String getResponse() throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
    String a = "";
    for (int b; ((b = is.read(buffer)) > 0); ) {
        a = new String(buffer, 0, b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        Log(a);
    }
    return a;
}
```

The loop never ends, causing the thread to be stuck, and even if the loop ends the program will just return after that causing the program to end. I need to know how I can have it set up to receive data 24/7 and then send data back after I received response.

Comment: How much data do you want to read? And what should happen if only part of the data is ready? And why can't you just use another thread?

Comment: Sounds like you called run instead of start on the new thread...

Comment: And the socket doesn't know how much data there is. That's why you have to know. Imagine parcels coming along a conveyor belt or something, and you're sitting there collecting them, you have no idea when the last parcel is (unless someone put a tag on it saying LAST, or they told you how many to collect, ...).